# jQuery plugins create 'not a function' error when loaded via Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack-2

I recently led in implementing Webpack in our chaotic JavaScript directory in a Rails app. I won't give the backstory unless requested, but this is a recurring problem I haven't found a good solution to:

Our app uses jQuery and a handful of jQuery plugins. For this post, I'll use Froala Editor as the example. (https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor)

The shortest description of the problem is this: upon loading the page that calls on froalaEditor, we're getting an error
`Uncaught TypeError: n(...).find(...).froalaEditor is not a function`
And trying to access the plugin after load yields a similar error.

Clearly the page doesn't have Froala correctly loaded. After a bit of logging and debugging, it *seems* like the Froala module imports jQuery and attaches to that instance of `$`, but is then overwritten when our app imports jQuery explicitly.

In terms of file structure and attempted solutions, we currently have a main js file that has our `TextEditor` module as a dependency. And in the `TextEditor` module, we `require('froala-editor')`.

I've tried using `imports-loader` to force Froala to use a 'global' instance of jQuery, but it doesn't seem to matter.

```
module.exports = {
  test: require.resolve('froala-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js'),
  use: [{
    loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false,exports=>false,jQuery=>jquery,$=>jquery,jquery=>jquery'
  }]
}
```

I've tried using `ProvidePlugin`:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
```

Also interestingly, the environment seems to change the results. I imagine it's just a load time thing, but if I just directly `require('froala-editor')` in our main js file, the problem seems to disappear locally, but stays broken in production.

Definitely at my wit's end with this thing, and since I'm not a Webpack pro, all the moving parts make this very difficult to debug.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interest of helping anybody else who might come across this (pretty specific) issue...

Local and production were behaving differently because production was consistently running `yarn install` at deploy. (I had run it fairly recently locally, but found myself using `npm install` to update packages). 
In a fun bit of chasing, I discovered that, despite the existence of `yarn.lock`, yarn will overwrite it anytime `yarn install` is run. It doesn't act much like my normal idea of a lock.

So, long story short: something was askew in my `yarn.lock` file. I believe there may be an issue with an updated package, but after reverting the lockfile to a previously working commit, I was able to run `yarn install` and get things working okay.

Definitely some stupidity on my part, but I think the way yarn uses the lockfile was totally unexpected and is worth sharing.

Answer (score -1):

To use multiple jquery versions or different js frameworks ::

```
var jq13 = jQuery.noConflict(false);
```

or

```
var jq13 = $.noConflict(false);

or 

var jq13 = $.noConflict();
```

and use variable which has refernce to diff version of jquery instead of $ or jQuery in statements as::

```
jq13('#id').hide();
```

if block of code uses $ and you dont want to change code the pass $ as parameter to the function as ::

```
jq13(function($){
$('#id').hide();
 });
```

I hope this code will help you help you.
Since $ used for refer to JQuery and most of js frameworks and plugins. If we use multiple versions of jquery or js frameworks $ get overwritten to js which loaded last.

Comment: Thank you for responding.
If I'm understanding correctly, this will set up 2 instances of jQuery, and I will need to use them differently, depending on the case. Since we have multiple plugins it would be preferable to not have to track which plugins are attached to which instance of jQuery.
The ultimate goal would be to simply attach each plugin to the globally used instance of jQuery.

Comment: then use $.noConflict() this free $ from jquery rrference.